# Restrict android app not to run on STB/ Android Tv

Tags: android, android-tv

I have two questions, I Google them but can't find any thing :(

**Question 1**

can any android app run on STB?

**Question 2**

Is there any way on which we can restrict our android app not to run on STB?

**Background**

I had an app previously which can run on android Tabs,Phone and STBs now I want separate apps for STB and Tabs/Phones.

Is there a way to restrict your app??

I have locally develop STB which follows no specific standard. and it hardware is somehow similar to Tabs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about any STP, but for Nexus Player which runs lollipop, you can install android app if you have the APK. TV apps use the same structure as those for phones and tablets.  If you didn't make the app for Nexus player, it will not show up on the Play Store. If the person has your APK, they could install it threw ADB. To show up in the Play store, TV apps need to meet some [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tv.html).

There is no way to restrict your app to run on STB since they use same structure for mobile apps.

What you can do is is use [multiple APK](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)  or add code to your [manifest](http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tv.html) file to allow your APK to work on mobile and TV. 
If you dont add those requirement, You app will stil work on STB, but not very good.